# How to vertically align title in LaTex

Tags: vertical-alignment, titles

I'm finishing my master's thesis and would like to move the title vertically more down towards center of the page...I googled, but couldn't get it to work =/

Here is a portion of my code from the beginning, which creates the title page:

```
\begin{document}
%\layout
\title{My title}
\author{My name}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} 

\vfill
\begin{flushright}
My name
My Faculty 
2013
etc
\end{flushright}

\newpage
.
.
.
```

Now with this code my title goes to the very top of the first page...how to modify the code so that I can move it around vertically? I also tried to put `\vspace` above the `\maketitle`, but the title remained where it was...:S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\vspace*` doesn't seem to like being put before a title. A work around is to add vertical space to the `\title`

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{article}
\begin{document}

\title{\vspace{30mm}My title}
\author{My name}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} 

\begin{flushright}
My name\\
My Faculty\\
2013\\
etc
\end{flushright}

\newpage
\end{document}
```

This would lower your entire title section by 30mm.